# How can I return a JSON object from ASP.Net WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to return something like this but it doesn't work:

```
if (user == null)
{
    return Ok({name: true});
}
return Ok({name: false);
```

Can someone tell me how I can make it return a value of true of false for a element "name" from my action method.

Comment: can you not return just a bool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Web API, create a class to have your property Name:

```
public class NameResponse {
    public bool Name { get; set; }
}
```

And return the JSON like this:

```
Request.CreateResponse<NameResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, new NameResponse() { Name = true });
```

If you're not using Web API and using a normal Controller you need to do this:

```
if (user == null)
{
    return Json(new { name = true });
}
return Json(new { name = false });
```